# Map result in Angular 4 from Asp.Net Core

Tags: javascript, angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, angular-http

How can I map result from Asp.Net Core API in my Angular app?

Here's my controller method which return data well:

```
[HttpGet("[action]"), Produces("application/json")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetBooks()
{
     return Ok(new
     {
          result = await _bookService.GetBooks()
     });
}
```

and my angular component:

```
export class BookComponent {
    public books: Book[];

    constructor(http: Http, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
        console.log("test");
        http.get(baseUrl + 'api/Book/GetBooks')
            .subscribe(res => {
                console.log(res.json());
            },
            error => console.error(error));
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error message:

> ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong?

UPDATE:

```
console.dir(res) returns:
Response headers : Headers {_headers: Map(8), _normalizedNames:
Map(8)} ok : true status : 200 statusText : "OK" type : 2 url :
"http://localhost:63530/api/Book/GetBooks"
_body : HTML CODE
__proto__ : Body
```

Comment: "Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0" nearly always means that the server is returning an HTML error page, a login page, (or XML, but since you have `Produces("application/json")`, probably not the case). `console.dir(res)` and inspect its `body`. What's in there (please edit the question with that, or any other relevant information)?

Comment: @msanford I have updated my post. Moreover, I've tested API by Swagger and it returns data well.

Comment: Thanks. You see, `_body` contains HTML, which is your problem. What is that HTML? A login page? Something you expect in a different context? Maybe you're missing an authentication/bearer token, header, or something else...

Comment: @msanford It's a new app and I do not have authentication at all.

Answer (score 0):

As msanford said, you are returning Html. This is why => HttpGet("[action]"). Just leave HttpGet.

Comment: paste http://localhost:63530/api/Book/GetBooks on the browser and see what you get, if is not a Json you have a problem on the back end

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the URL which was not correct.